# DC component of a discrete filter

Tags: filters, filter-design

I know that many books and papers talk about the DC offset/DC component of a filter. How do we define the DC offset mathematically, for the case of discrete filters?

Comment: Do you mean the "DC offset of a *signal*" rather than a filter?

Comment: @Juancho: a few terms are used interchangeably, DC offset/ DC component of filter. I am not sure which one is used commonly.

Comment: Could you point to one of those many books/papers that mention DC offset of a "filter"?

Comment: @AtulIngle: page 10 of this document: [http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.2334&rep=rep1&type=pdf][1]

Comment: It looks like when they say zero DC, they mean "band pass filter" (see page 4). And when they say DC component they just mean frequency response at zero frequency. For instance, see Eq. (20) where they evaluate $G_b(0)$. That's the answer to your question. You can define the DC offset of the filter response as its gain at zero frequency. If that makes sense, I'll convert this comment to an answer.

Comment: Can it be intepreted as the sum of all the coefficients of the filter?

Comment: @AtulIngle Makes sense to me.  Go for it.

Comment: @freak_warrior  The sum of the coefficients of a FIR filter is its gain at 0 Hz.

Comment: @freak, that link to citeseer doesn't work.  can't get the document.

is this about the DC offset in the output of a IIR filter due to a limit cycle?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a (working) link to a paper relevant to the OP: http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.80.2334&rep=rep1&type=pdf

It looks like when they say zero DC, they mean "band pass filter" (see page 4). And when they say DC component they just mean frequency response at zero frequency. For instance, see Eq. (20) where they evaluate $G_b(0)$. That's the answer to your question: you can define the DC offset of the filter response as its gain at zero frequency.